# O que são Native Hybrid e Web Applications?

Tags: php, android, aplicação-web, mobile

Olá pessoal estou meio perdido no estudo da computação móvel  estou estudando esses 3 tipos de arquitetura para desenvolvimento mobile alguém sabe a definição dessas arquiteturas de desenvolvimento ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Native ou Nativa**

São aplicações desenvolvidas utilizando a linguagem de programação específica do dispositivo, como por exemplo, Java para Android, Objective-C para iOS da Apple. As vantagens de desenvolver uma aplicação móvel utilizando sua linguagem padrão são: velocidade, segurança, acesso aos dispositivos do aparelho, como por exemplo, câmera, GPS, etc.

> **Hybrid ou Híbrida**

O desenvolvimento de aplicações híbridas traz o melhor dos dois mundos (Nativo e Web) para o ambiente de desenvolvimento. Estes tipos de aplicações são desenvolvidas utilizando a tecnologia Web e então empacotadas para uma plataforma específica. Isto permite que estas aplicações se comportem como nativas. Assim como aplicativos Web, também pode ocorrer problemas de compatibilidade.
Exemplo desta abordagem é o [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

> **Web Applications**

Aplicativos Web (executados a partir dos navegadores dos dispositivos), são multiplataforma, pois, todos os smartphones atuais têm navegadores modernos e, suportam as tecnologias mais recentes necessárias para o bom funcionamento da aplicação. Contudo, podem enfrentar problemas de compatibilidade tendo sempre que otimizar o código para contornar tais problemas.

Comment: Excelente muito obrigado !