# Aplicação MVC ou SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, single-page-application

Já venho trabalhando com MVC nos últimos dois anos, mas ultimamente tenho acompanhado o crescimento do desenvolvimento das aplicações em SPA. Após ler diversos artigos sobre este assunto me surgiu uma dúvida, caso eu queira desenvolver uma aplicação a ser publicada tanto na web quanto mobile o SPA seria a melhor indicação ou deveria fazer um mix entre MVC e SPA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que é melhor para você em cada caso só você poderá dizer.

As duas tecnologias não concorrem entre si, então não há dicotomia. Se quiser use ambas. O ASP.NET MVC é uma tecnologia de servidor. O SPA é uma tecnologia de cliente.

É verdade que o uso O ASP.NET MVC possui *views* e o SPA quase não precisa disto (mas precisa um pouco), ele é a *view*. É mais comum usar neste caso o ASP.NET WebAPI. Mas que por sorte no [ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101) passou a ser integrado.

Se usar o SPA está utilizando uma tecnologia web, ou seja, pode usar em qualquer dispositivo que tenha um navegador web padrão. A pergunta fala em mobile. Até existem tecnologias que usam a web como base para os aplicativos, mas não deixa de ser web. Normalmente ou se usa esta tecnologia ou se faz o aplicativo com a API nativa do sistema operacional do dispositivo móvel. Aí obviamente o SPA não é possível. No servidor pode continuar usar o ASP.NET WebAPI (agora muito provavelmente com [ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101)).

Muitas pessoas gostam usar web para tudo, o que costuma ser um erro. Tem inúmeras desvantagens e a única vantagem de fato é aproveitar o código do cliente para todos dispositivos (e nem é tão simples assim). O código do servidor pode ser aproveitado mais facilmente. Mesmo assim alguns preferem algo mais específico quando o acesso é do cliente é feito de forma nativa.

Note que SPA só costuma ser útil para aplicativos. Para sites comuns é melhor usar a apresentação normal web, até por questões de SEO. Claro, em alguns pontos talvez até caiba o uso do SPA, mas só se deve adotar isto, mesmo que pontualmente, em algumas páginas específicas quando se tem pleno domínio das consequências. Não pode estudar superficialmente e sair fazendo seguindo receitas de bolo. Por isto hoje boa parte dos sites são feitas de forma errada.

Algumas perguntas no site que podem ajudar

- [Quando utilizar Cordova ou Xamarin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79939/101)
- [Criar layout para aplicações PHP e .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110691/101)
- [Por que usar o AngularJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123913/101)
- [O que são Native Hybrid e Web Applications?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83321/101)
- [É possível criar uma aplicação híbrida multiplataforma com PhoneGap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91960/101)

Tem coisa que o leigo costuma gostar, quando ganha experiência descobre que é uma porcaria. Outros nunca ficam experientes e acham bom pra sempre, mesmo que seja horrível.

Mas tenha em mente que não tem solução mágica. Se as coisas fossem mais fáceis em computação, 90% do programadores não teriam o que fazer. Nem por isso não se deva tentar simplificar. Mas a simplificação não é a única, muito menos a principal característica que uma aplicação deve ter. Além disto, o que pode parecer ser simplificação muitas vezes é complicação.

Hoje dá para fazer SPA com C#: [O que é ASP.NET Core Blazor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bigown, a sua resposta foi muuuuito além do que esperava! Vlw mesmo pelas dicas e principalmente pelos links, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Então acha que não seria correto criar um sistema 100% SPA? Ate cheguei fazer um tópico sobre: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154739/web-moderna-spa-rest?noredirect=1#comment319468_154739 @bigown

Comment: @Marcial Correto é algo que depende de contexto. O problema é justamente as pessoas acharem que existe resposta única para tudo. O que minha experiência indica é o que está na resposta.  Não sei se teria algo a acrescentar. Mas se tiver específicas e que não dependam de opinião pode fazer uma pergunta no site. A resposta existente lá é um um pouco ingênua. Apesar da boa vontade, ela peca em algumas coisas talvez justamente por ter pouca experiência.